# POST /api/ HTTP/1.1 400 411 error when posting data from flutter to Django rest API

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework

I have a form with text inputs, and I have created a button as well which when pressed, should post the input field data into a Django Api. But when I press the button, I get a "POST /api/ HTTP/1.1" 400 411 Error.

This is sample from my code:

```
var nameController = TextEditingController();
  var phoneController = TextEditingController();
  var purposeController = TextEditingController();
  var addressController = TextEditingController();
  var visiteeController = TextEditingController();
  var dateController = TextEditingController();
  var idController = TextEditingController(text: generateRandomId());
  var timeInController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _postDataToDjango() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> formData = {
      "visitor_name": nameController.text,
      "visit_date": dateController.text,
      "Time_in": timeInController.text,
      "Time_out": timeOutController.text,
      "Department": dropDownController.text,
      "Visitee_name": visiteeController.text,
      "Address": addressController.text,
      "Phone": phoneController.text,
      "Purpose_of_visit": purposeController.text
    };

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: jsonEncode(formData),
      );

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      print('Data posted successfully');
    }
    else {
      print('Error posting data: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
```

I have tried to check if there was something wrong with the url and I have added a header to the body yet nothing happens.